# Is it possible to serve React from Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

I'm new to back-end coding, and I'm struggling to understand exactly what a "fullstack" app would look like.
Is it:

- A Node-Express server that serves `index.html`, which has `<script src="main.jsx"></script>` in it (If this is the case, how would the `.jsx` content get compiled into browser-ready javascript?)
- A Node-Express server that serves some data (`.json`) + a frontend app (that you would initialize with Vite or CRA) that fetches from said server?

Answer (score 1):

Both are currect , your server can serve content to the cliend (first case) or send data to the client (`json` , `xml` or etc).

Note that when you are working with react and `.jsx` component you have to build your project and server the html file (including `js` , `css`) via `express` server

Comment: Do I have to build it? How come when I just use Vite, and I start up a dev server (`npm run dev`), all `.jsx` files are understood by the browser, and they don't have to build anything? I don't see any `build` or `dist` folder.

Comment: in development mode , files are build but not stored in the file system , instead its stored in memory temporary

Comment: if you run `npm run build` or `vite build` build files are stored in your file system